# C# Simplify property selector in constructor with Generic Type

Tags: c#

I'd like to simplify some code, if possible.

**Current Constructor** (T is within the scope, defined in the outer type)

```
public Column(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

    _ = propertyInfo ?? throw new ArgumentException(message: $"Property {propertyName} does not exist on {typeof(T).Name}");

    ...
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to make `property` a Lambda expression or something to select the property of Generic Type `T`.

This of course is to make our development easier with fewer mistakes.

**Current use**

`new DataTable<someClass>.Column(nameof(someClass.someProperty))`

I would like to do something like:

`new DataTable<someClass>.Column(someClass.someProperty)` (without declaring a new `someClass`)

*OR*

`new DataTable<someClass>.Column(t = > t.someProperty)`

Comment: You can accept a `Func<T, U>` or a `Expression<Func<T, U>>`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the property?

Comment: To expand: yes you absolutely can. But what route you take depends on whether you *need* a `PropertyInfo`, or whether you can use a delegate which gets/sets that property directly. This is why @JohnathanBarclay is asking for more information. Once we have it, we can give you a specific answer.

Comment: You are aware that `DataTable<T>.Column` is a method, not a constructor, something you present in your first code example?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, I just need to get the `PropertyInfo`. I have custom attributes that contain basic column information that is being used when building a Data Table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below method to extract property name from Expression

```
    public static PropertyInfo GetAccessedMemberInfo<T>(this Expression<T> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression? memberExpression = null;

        if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            memberExpression = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a member access", "expression");
        }

        return memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo ?? throw new Exception();
    }
```

Then use it like this

```
public Column(Expression<Func<T, object>> prop)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = prop.GetAccessedMemberInfo();
}

new DataTable<someClass>.Column(t = > t.someProperty)
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is more complete and support more scenarios, but also more complex.

If you don't need such flexibility, this enforces you to strongly type and also makes sure that the constructor never throws

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    public class Column<T, TProperty>
    {
        Func<T, TProperty> functionToBeApplied;

        // Pass a function, it can never throw
        public Column(Func<T, TProperty> functionToBeApplied)
        {
            this.functionToBeApplied = functionToBeApplied;
        }

        // Apply the function to the object
        public string GetPropertyAsString(T obj)
        {
            TProperty property = functionToBeApplied(obj);
            return property.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var column = new Column<string, int>(x => x.Length);

            Console.WriteLine($"Size of string is {column.GetPropertyAsString("this is my object")}");
        }
    }
}
```